# How to duplicate request on two instances AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two EC2 instances (prod and test) and I want to duplicate prod received requests to test instance. How can I do it in AWS infrastructure? Sorry, I cannot give you some code and examples, because I can't imagine how this is possible. I hope for your understanding

Comment: @KaiBurjack, yes, all instances have the same data. It will be an HTTP request and I just want to share this request to test instance and to production.

Comment: @KaiBurjack Yes, but we have a monitoring system and we can get all information about requests that test instances get. We only need to mirror request to the test instance from production

Comment: Don't forget that an HTTP request also has a Response, and some HTML pages might invoke multiple HTTP requests (eg style sheets, images, API calls). Sending the 'live' request to a second instance won't be quite the same. It might be better to 'record' the requests (eg in a database or in files) and enable 'replay' later -- this has the benefit that it can be done multiple times and at any later time, rather than 'at the same time'. It's also a great way to debug a situation by replaying requests one-at-a-time to identify what happened in that particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are some of the options;

**A :**

1. Write a AWS lambda to forward HTTP request to your production as well as test ec2 instances. If you have response, then in lambda code wait for response from production instance and then send back same as response from this lambda.
2. Create AWS Application Load Balancer and create ALB routing rule based on your production host and path, with target as the AWS lambda function created in step A.1)

**B :**

Build logic within your application to asynchronously forward HTTP request to test ec2 instance from production ec2 instance

Comment: And Traffic Mirroring :)